Attempt to upgrade via apt and fails
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libclang-cpp14t64 libllvm14t64 libllvmspirvlib14 libopencl-clang14
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Get more security updates through Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled:
  libcjson1 libavdevice60 ffmpeg libpostproc57 libavcodec60 libavutil58
  libswscale7 libswresample4 libavformat60 libavfilter9
Learn more about Ubuntu Pro at https://ubuntu.com/pro
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libigdfcl1
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/34.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 118 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 79, <STDIN> line 1.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
(Reading database ... 125127 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libigdfcl1_1.0.16900.24-914~22.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libigdfcl1 (1.0.16900.24-914~22.04) over (1.0.15468.25-2build1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libigdfcl1_1.0.16900.24-914~22.04_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencl-clang.so.14', which is also in package libopencl-clang14:amd64 14.0.0-4build2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libigdfcl1_1.0.16900.24-914~22.04_amd64.deb
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I try apt upgrade and get a dpkg error. I am not sure what is going on. I did apt-mark hold on the kernel because latest kernel breaks intel arc gpu encoding. So I am one kernel revision behind. I am wondering if that has to do with the upgrade failure?

The errors indicate that the package libigdfcl1 is trying to overwrite a file owned by libopencl-clang.
You can run the following command to accept this overwrite.
sudo apt -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" full-upgrade

